# How can ı create login authentication from a tab screen using react navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I designed two tab screens. One of them can be accessed by everyone ,we need to login to the other. I am using API to login. If the username and password are correct, the login process is completed. But after logging in , ı cannot switch to the main page screen without refreshing from console. Likewise, when I want to logout , I need to refresh from console. I could not do the opening process directly, I think there is a problem with my stack connections. Stack connection is  App.js --> MainTabScreen.js --> SettingScreen.js --> ListScreen.js
[1.png - App.js --> MainTabScreen.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67sKB.jpg)
[2.png - SettingScreen.js --> ListScreen.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S32Co.jpg)
`
[SplashScreen[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S32Co.jpg)[MainScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U1LR.jpg)

```
               //App.js
            import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
            import  React , {useEffect} from 'react';
            import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
            //Navigation
            import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
            //Mobx
            import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
            //Store
            import { store } from './STORE/index'
            //Async
            import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
            //Screens
            import MainTabScreen from './SCREENS/TABS/MainTabScreen';
            
            export default observer(() => {
              useEffect(() => {
                (async () => {
                  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token');
                  store.setStore('SET_TOKEN', token);  
                })();
              }, []);
              
              return (
                <NavigationContainer>
                    <MainTabScreen/>
                </NavigationContainer>
              )
            })
            const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
        
                import  React , { useEffect , Component} from 'react';
            import { StyleSheet, Image, Text, View ,Dimensions, TextInput} from 'react-native';
            import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
            import { createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
            //Store
            import { store } from '../../STORE/index';
            //Async
            import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
            //Screens
            import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
            import SettingScreen from './SettingScreen';
            import TestScreen from './TestScreen';
            //menuScreens
            import WhiteListScreen from '../MENUSCREEN/WhiteListScreen';
            import Reports from '../MENUSCREEN/Reports';
            import SendNotifications from '../MENUSCREEN/SendNotifications';
            //Color
            import COLORS from '../../COLOR/color'
            //Vectoricons
            import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
            import { BlurView } from 'expo-blur';
            
            //MainTabScreen.js
            
            const WINDOW_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
            const WINDOW_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;
            
            const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
            const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator();
            const TestStack = createStackNavigator();
            const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
            
            
            
            function MainTabScreen({navigation}) {
              useEffect(() => {
                (async () => {
                  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token');
                  const ip_address = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ip_address');
                   
                  store.setStore('SET_TOKEN', token);
                  store.setStore('SET_IPADDRESS', ip_address);
                  
                })();
              }, []);
              return (
                <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
                  tabBarStyle: { position: 'absolute' ,backgroundColor: 'black'},
                  tabBarBackground: () => (
                    <BlurView tint="light" intensity={20} style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}  />
                    
                  ),
                }} >
                  <Tab.Screen
                    name="Home"
                    component={HomeStackScreen}   
                    options={{
                      tabBarLabel:'Home',
                      tabBarLabelStyle: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                      
                      },
                      headerShown: false,
                      tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
                        <Ionicons name="home-outline" color={color} size={20} 
                      />),   
                      tabBarActiveTintColor: COLORS.rawColor,
                      tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
                    }}
                  >
                  </Tab.Screen>
               
                  <Tab.Screen
                    name="Setting"
                    component={SettingStackScreen}
                    options={{
                      tabBarLabel:'Settings',
                      tabBarLabelStyle: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                      },
                      headerShown: false,
                      tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
                        <Ionicons name="settings-outline" color={color} size={20} 
                      />),      
                      tabBarActiveTintColor: COLORS.rawColor,
                      tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
                    }}
                  /> 
                    <Tab.Screen
                    name="Test"
                    component={TestStackScreen}
                    options={{
                      tabBarLabel:'Test',
                      tabBarLabelStyle: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                      },
                      headerShown: false,
                      tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
                        <Ionicons name="close" color={color} size={20} 
                      />),      
                      tabBarActiveTintColor: COLORS.rawColor,
                      tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
                    }}
                  /> 
                </Tab.Navigator>
              
              );
            
            };
            
            export default MainTabScreen;
            
            const TestStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
              <TestStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
                headerTransparent: { position: 'absolute' ,backgroundColor: 'black'},
                tabBarBackground: () => (
                  <BlurView tint="light" intensity={30} style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}  />
                  
                ),
                headerTintColor: '#000',
                
              }}>
                <TestStack.Screen name="menu" component={TestScreen}
                  options={{
                  headerTitle: (props) => ( // App Logo
                  <Image
                    style={{  width: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 120 : 100, 
                              height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 100 : 50, 
                              }}
                    source={require('../../assets/Optima-logo.png')}
                    resizeMode='contain'
                  />),
                    headerRight: () => (
                      <Ionicons style={styles.drawerStyle}
                        name="settings"
                        color="black"
                        size={25}
                        backgroundColor="#E2E7EA"
                        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}> </Ionicons>
                    )
                  }} />
            
                <TestStack.Screen name="WhiteListScreen" component={WhiteListScreen}
                      options={{
                      headerTitle: (props) => ( // App Logo
                      <Image
                        style={{  width: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 120 : 100, 
                                  height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 100 : 50, 
                                  }}
                        source={require('../../assets/Optima-logo.png')}
                        resizeMode='contain'
                      />),
                        headerRight: () => (
                          <Ionicons style={styles.drawerStyle}
                            name="settings"
                            color="black"
                            size={25}
                            backgroundColor="#E2E7EA"
                            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}> </Ionicons>
                        )
                      }} />
                   <TestStack.Screen name="Reports" component={Reports}
                      options={{
                      headerTitle: (props) => ( // App Logo
                      <Image
                        style={{  width: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 120 : 100, 
                                  height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 100 : 50, 
                                  }}
                        source={require('../../assets/Optima-logo.png')}
                        resizeMode='contain'
                      />),
                        headerRight: () => (
                          <Ionicons style={styles.drawerStyle}
                            name="settings"
                            color="black"
                            size={25}
                            backgroundColor="#E2E7EA"
                            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}> </Ionicons>
                        )
                      }} />
                     <TestStack.Screen name="SendNotifications" component={SendNotifications}
                      options={{
                      headerTitle: (props) => ( // App Logo
                      <Image
                        style={{  width: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 120 : 100, 
                                  height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 100 : 50, 
                                  }}
                        source={require('../../assets/Optima-logo.png')}
                        resizeMode='contain'
                      />),
                        headerRight: () => (
                          <Ionicons style={styles.drawerStyle}
                            name="settings"
                            color="black"
                            size={25}
                            backgroundColor="#E2E7EA"
                            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}> </Ionicons>
                        )
                      }} />
              </TestStack.Navigator>
            );
            
            
            const HomeStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
              <HomeStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
                headerTransparent: { position: 'absolute' ,backgroundColor: 'black'},
                tabBarBackground: () => (
                  <BlurView tint="light" intensity={30} style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}  />
                  
                ),
                headerTintColor: '#000',
                
              }}>
                <HomeStack.Screen name="menu" component={HomeScreen}
                  options={{
                  headerTitle: (props) => ( // App Logo
                  <Image
                    style={{  width: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 120 : 100, 
                              height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 100 : 50, 
                              }}
                    source={require('../../assets/Optima-logo.png')}
                    resizeMode='contain'
                  />),
                    headerRight: () => (
                      <Ionicons style={styles.drawerStyle}
                        name="settings"
                        color="black"
                        size={25}
                        backgroundColor="#E2E7EA"
                        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}> </Ionicons>
                    )
                  }} />
            
              </HomeStack.Navigator>
            );
            
              const SettingStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
                
                <SettingsStack.Navigator  screenOptions={{
                  headerTransparent: { position: 'absolute' ,backgroundColor: 'black'},
                  tabBarBackground: () => (
                    <BlurView tint="light" intensity={30} style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}/>   
                  ),
                  headerTintColor: '#000',  
                }}>
                  <SettingsStack.Screen name="SettingScreen" component={SettingScreen}
                    options={{
                    headerTitle: (props) => ( // App Logo
                    <Image
                      style={{ width: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 120 : 120, height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 120 : 120 }}
                      source={require('../../assets/Optima-logo.png')}
                      resizeMode='contain'
                    />),
                      headerRight: () => (
                        <Ionicons style={styles.drawerStyle}
                          name="settings"
                          color="black"
                          size={25}
                          backgroundColor="#E2E7EA"
                          onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}> </Ionicons>
                      )
                    }} />
                    {/* {store.token ? 
                       <Stack.Screen 
                       options={{headerShown: false}} 
                       name="SignInScreen" component={SignInScreen}/> 
                       :
                       <Stack.Screen 
                       name="ListScreen" component={ListScreen}/>  
                    } */}
                  
                     
                    {/* <Stack.Screen 
                      options={{headerShown: false}} 
                      name="SignInScreen" component={SignInScreen}/> 
                    <Stack.Screen 
                      name="ListScreen" component={ListScreen}/>   
                   
                    <Stack.Screen 
                      
                      name="WhiteListScreen" component={WhiteListScreen}/>   
                    */}
                </SettingsStack.Navigator>
            
              );
            
  
              
            });
        
        //SettingScreen.js
        
            import React, { useEffect } from "react";
        import {
          Dimensions,
          StyleSheet,
          ImageBackground,
          View
        } from "react-native";
        import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native-paper";
        import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
        //Store
        import { store } from "../../STORE/index";
        //Color
        import COLORS from "../../COLOR/color";
        //Screens
        import SignInScreen from "../SignInScreen";
        import ListScreen from "../TABS/ListScreen";
        import CashierSignIn from "../TABS/CashierSignIn";
        
        const WINDOW_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
        const WINDOW_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height;
        
        const Stack = createStackNavigator();
        const ListStack = createStackNavigator();
        
        const userToken = store.token;
        
        
        export default function SettingSreen({ navigation }) {
        
          const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
          useEffect(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              setIsLoading(false);
            }, 1000)
          }, []);
        
          if (isLoading && !userToken) {
            return (
              <View>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
              </View>
            )
          }
        
          return (
            <ImageBackground
              source={require("../../IMAGE/background3.png")}
              style={{ width: WINDOW_WIDTH, height: WINDOW_HEIGHT }}
            >
              {!userToken ? (
                <Stack.Navigator ListScreen={props => <ListScreen {...props} />}
                  screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} >
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="CashierSignIn"
                    component={CashierSignIn}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="SignInScreen"
                    component={SignInScreen}
                  />
                </Stack.Navigator>
              ) : (
                <ListStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
                  <ListStack.Screen
                    name="ListScreen"
                    component={ListScreen}
                  />
                </ListStack.Navigator>
              )}
            </ImageBackground>
          );
        }
        
        const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
        import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {
      Text,
      View,
      Dimensions,
      StyleSheet,
      ImageBackground,
      TouchableOpacity,
    } from "react-native";
    
    import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
    import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
    
    //Translation
    import i18n from "../../TRANSLATION/I18n";
    //Store
    import { store } from "../../STORE/index";
    //SignIn Screen
    import SignInScreen from "../SignInScreen";
    //Color
    import COLORS from "../../COLOR/color";
    //Screens
    import ListScreen from "./ListScreen";
    
    
    //CashierSignIn.js
    const WINDOW_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
    const WINDOW_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height;
    
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    
    
    
    export default function CashierSignIn({ navigation }) {
      return (
        <ImageBackground
          source={require("../../IMAGE/background3.png")}
          style={{ width: WINDOW_WIDTH, height: WINDOW_HEIGHT }}
        >
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.logo}></Text>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={styles.forgot}></Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SignInScreen")}
              style={styles.loginBtn}
            >
              <Text style={styles.loginText}> Cashier Sign In </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      );
    }
    //SignInScreen and List Screen
    
    
        import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import {
      View,
      Text,
      Dimensions,
      StyleSheet,
      TouchableOpacity,
      ImageBackground,
      TextInput,
      LogBox,
      Alert
    } from "react-native";
    //Axios
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native-paper";
    //Store
    import { store } from "../STORE/index";
    //COLOR
    import COLORS from "../COLOR/color";
    //Icons
    import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
    //AsyncStorage
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
    
    LogBox.ignoreLogs([
      'Require cycle:'
    ]);
    
    const WINDOW_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
    const WINDOW_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height;
    
    
    export default function SignInScreen({ navigation }) {
      const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
      const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
      const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setIsLoading(false);
        }, 1000)
      }, []);
    
      if (isLoading) {
        return (
          <View>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
          </View>
        )
      }
    
      const loginUser = () => {
        if (!username.trim() || !password.trim()) {
          Alert.alert(
            '' + i18n.t('usernamePasswordValid'),
            ''
            [
            { text: i18n.t('ok'), onPress: () => null }
            ]
          );
          return;
        } else {
          axios.get(`http://172.16.55.36:8004/api/values/gettoken?username=${username}&password=${password}`)
            .then((response) => {
              console.log(response)
              AsyncStorage.setItem('id_token', response.data.data).then(() => {
                store.setStore('SET_TOKEN', response.data.data)
                setIsLoading(true);
              })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            })
        }
      }
      return (
        <ImageBackground
          source={require("../IMAGE/background3.png")}
          style={{ width: WINDOW_WIDTH, height: WINDOW_HEIGHT }}
    
        >
          <View style={styles.header}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('CashierSignIn')}>
              <Text alignItems="center">
                <Icon name="close" color={COLORS.rawColor} size={30} />
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.container}>
    
            <Text style={styles.logo}>Optima Ticketing App</Text>
            <View style={styles.inputView}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.inputText}
                placeholder="Username"
                placeholderTextColor={COLORS.white}
                onChangeText={(username) => setUsername(username)}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputView}>
              <TextInput
                secureTextEntry
                style={styles.inputText}
                placeholder="Password"
                placeholderTextColor={COLORS.white}
                onChangeText={(password) => setPassword(password)}
              />
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignUpScreen')}>
              <Text style={styles.forgot}>Forgot Password?</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            {/* <TouchableOpacity   onPress={loginUser ? navigation.navigate('ListScreen') : alert("test")} style={styles.loginBtn}> */}
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={loginUser} style={styles.loginBtn}>
              <Text style={styles.loginText}>LOGIN</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignUpScreen')}
                style={styles.loginText} >Signup</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      );
    }
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';
//Store
import { store } from "../../STORE/index";


//AsyncStorage
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const WINDOW_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const WINDOW_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;


function ListScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={require("../../IMAGE/background3.png")}
      style={{ width: WINDOW_WIDTH, height: WINDOW_HEIGHT }}
    >

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('WhiteListScreen')}>
          <Text>White List</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity >
          <Text>2.screen</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={async () => {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('id_token')
              .then(() => store.setStore('SET_TOKEN', null))
              .then(() => navigation.goBack())
          }}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}> Log Out </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  )
}

export default ListScreen;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Got any visuals of the code running? It would be easier to understand how to block it off if we knew what it looked like.

Comment: I shared my full project

Answer (score 1):

I would create a context or utility that checks for login status. Then make the drawer conditionally render a login screen/button, or whatever content you'd like, based on that status.

Comment: That's where your nav container should be. Make sure you're wrapping your entire application in the context, nav container and all.

Comment: Honestly that tutorial seems pretty dense and isn't to my taste. First things first, learn how context works in general. There are a lot of great uses for context beside auth. Once you have that under control, implementing auth to a context should be pretty straight forward (assuming you have knowledge of auth, which I don't)